# How to make script recursive

Tags: php, google-places-api

I was wondering if anyone could help me fine tune my script.

I have what I need but I'm just trying to figure out how to make it recursive.

e.g. I currently have:

```
$key    = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sensor = 'false';
$query  = 'Place 1';

$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key='.$key.'&query='.urlencode($query).'&sensor='.$sensor;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$places = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// echo $url;

$output = json_decode($places);


$i = 0;


while ($output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat != '') {
    echo '<strong>' . $query . '</strong><br />';
    echo $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat . ', '. $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lng;
    echo '<br />' . $output->results[$i]->formatted_address;
    echo '<hr />';

    $i++;
}

// there is a delay between when the next page token is given and when it is ready to be accessed
sleep(5);

if ($output->next_page_token != '') {

    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken='.$output->next_page_token.'&key='.$key.'&sensor='.$sensor;

    // repeating myself now!

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $places = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $output = json_decode($places);

    $i = 0;

    while ($output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat != '') {
        echo '<strong>' . $query . '</strong><br />';
        echo $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat . ', '. $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lng;
        echo '<br />' . $output->results[$i]->formatted_address;
        echo '<hr />';

        $i++;
    }


}
```

So, ideally, I am looking at how to restructure so that the above will run for as long as there is a next page token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least you could replace the `if` with a `while`. And maybe re-factor the body of the while into a function.

But you don't need to call it recursively, just iteratively until you're done (i.e. no more next page token)

```
function doQuery($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $places = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $output = json_decode($places);

    $i = 0;

    while ($output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat != '') {
        echo '<strong>' . $query . '</strong><br />';
        echo $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat . ', '. $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lng;
        echo '<br />' . $output->results[$i]->formatted_address;
        echo '<hr />';

        $i++;
    }

    sleep(5);

    return $output->next_page_token;
}

$next_page_token = doQuery($url);

while ($next_page_token != '') 
{
   $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken='.$next_page_token.'&key='.$key.'&sensor='.$sensor;

   $next_page_token = doQuery($url);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help Miky, probably should've thought of that but brain is dead figuring out this api....

Comment: this worked great. it was key to add a sleep function, since google returns an INVALID_REQUEST when you're hitting their API too rapidly. 2 seconds worked fine for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate your logic within a function, then loop while you have a next page token:

```
function doWorkAndPrint( $url, $query) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $places = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $output = json_decode($places);

    $i = 0;

    while ($output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat != '') {
        echo '<strong>' . $query . '</strong><br />';
        echo $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lat . ', '. $output->results[$i]->geometry->location->lng;
        echo '<br />' . $output->results[$i]->formatted_address;
        echo '<hr />';

        $i++;
    }

    return $output->next_page_token;
}
```

Now, you just need to loop while that function returns something useful. Since you want to do it at least once, I would use a `do ... while` loop:

```
$key    = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$sensor = 'false';
$query  = 'Place 1';

do {
    $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?pagetoken='.$query.'&key='.$key.'&sensor='.$sensor;
    $query = doWorkAndPrint( $url, $query);
} while( $query != '');
```